# Cannot publish any docker containers

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I had docker 1.7.1, I was following james turbnall the docker book .
created two images (apache, jekyll) , created a jekyll container then
I created apache container as well with the -P tag with EXPOSE 80 in the docker file but as i ran docker port  80 but no public port error.

then i upgraded to docker 1.8.1 but nothing changed I tried -P , -p , EXPOSE and every argument but i can't get it fixed .

My ports column when running Docker ps -a is always empty.

**Dockerfile:**

> FROM ubuntu:14.04
>
> MAINTAINER AbdelRhman Khaled
>
> ENV REFRESHED_AT 2015-09-05
>
> RUN apt-get -yqq update
>
> RUN apt-get -yqq install apache2
>
> VOLUME [ "/var/www/html" ]
>
> WORKDIR /var/www/html
>
> ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
>
> ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www.data
>
> ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
>
> ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2.pid
>
> ENV APACHE_RUN_DIR /var/run/apache2
>
> ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2
>
> RUN mkdir -p $APACHE_RUN_DIR $APACHE_LOCK_DIR $APACHE_LOG_DIR
>
> EXPOSE 80
>
> ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/sbin/apache2" ]
>
> CMD [ "-D", "FOREGROUND" ]

**commands:**

> $ sudo docker build -t jamtur01/apache .
>
> $ sudo docker run -d -P --volumes-from james_blog jamtur01/apache
>
> $ sudo docker port container_ID 80
>
> Error: No public port '80/tcp' published for aa99fef6544a

Comment: Could you post the Dockerfile and shell commands you're trying?

Answer (score 0):

Just changed the Image Tag name and All is working fine now.